# htaccess : can I delete old redirection rules?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Last year I altered existing URLs, so I created hunders of redirection rules to point each old URL to the new one.

Can I remove these rules today ? How can I check if google is no mre indexing old URLs ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the "advanced search" google offers:

it allows to use the `site` keyword, so a search for `site:example.com` will present *all* URLs indexed in the google catalog.

That should be the list you are interested in.

---

Apart from that you should have uploaded your current sitemap and checked that those current links are indexed, obviously.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is I have about 13.000 redirections, It won't be easy to check manually with the site: option :(

Comment: Well, you could write a script testing all rewritten URLs for their existence in the google catalog.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to analyze your http servers access log files and check if those rewritten URLs are used. That should also answer your question.